# Spring Gateway RouteLocator null Pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

```
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.Route;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinition;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionWriter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class RefreshableRoutesLocator implements RouteLocator {

    private RouteLocatorBuilder builder;
    private RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder routesBuilder;
    private Flux<Route> route;

    @Autowired
    GatewayRoutesRefresher gatewayRoutesRefresher;

    @Autowired
    private RouteDefinitionWriter routeDefinitionWriter;

    public void RefreshRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        this.builder = builder;
        clearRoutes();
    }

    public void clearRoutes() {
        routesBuilder = builder.routes();
    }

    public RefreshableRoutesLocator addRoute(@NotNull final String id, @NotNull final String path,
            @NotNull final URI uri) throws URISyntaxException {
        System.out.println("-----------");
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(uri.getScheme())) {
            throw new URISyntaxException("Missing scheme in URI: {}", uri.toString());
        }
        routesBuilder.route(id, fn -> fn.path(path + "/**").uri(uri));
        return this;
    }

    public RefreshableRoutesLocator addRoute(@NotNull RouteDefinition definition) {
        routeDefinitionWriter.save(Mono.just(definition)).subscribe();
        return this;
    }

    public void buildRoutes() {
        this.route = routesBuilder.build().getRoutes();
        gatewayRoutesRefresher.refreshRoutes();
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Route> getRoutes() {
        return route;
    }
}
```

I am using RefreshableRoutesLocator to load routes on spring startup from database but while starting i am getting exception

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Publisher
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: The mapper returned a null Publisher
```

On checking I found that route is null at start :

```
private Flux<Route> route;
```

Can someone help me to fix this, My Agenda is to load Routes dynamically from Database into spring gateway at startup event.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved once i supplied constructor :

```
@Autowired
    public RefreshableRoutesLocator(@NonNull final RouteLocatorBuilder builder,
            @NonNull final GatewayRoutesRefresher gatewayRoutesRefresher) {
        this.builder = builder;
        this.gatewayRoutesRefresher = gatewayRoutesRefresher;
        clearRoutes();
    }
```